# how to stop and start service in linix with dart

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, command, sudo

from a DART I am trying to make commands on an ubuntu machine to activate and deactivate services with the sudo password but I receive an error..
this is my code down:

the error :

```
error stderr:[sudo] password for bst: sudo: sudo:system.ctl status glutz-eaccess.service : comand not found    // by the way bst is a user in the ubuntu machine
```

is any help ? please

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> executeSudoCommand(String command, String sudoPassword) async {
  final process = await Process.start(
    'sudo',
    ['-S', command],
    runInShell: true,
  );

  process.stdin.writeln(sudoPassword);
  process.stdin.close();

  final stdout = await process.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  final stderr = await process.stderr.transform(utf8.decoder).join();

  print('stdout: $stdout');
  print('stderr: $stderr');

  final exitCode = await process.exitCode;
  print('Exit code: $exitCode');
}

void main() async {
  final sudoPassword = 'your_password';
  final commandToRun = 'sudo systemctl stop your-service-name'; // Corrected command

  await executeSudoCommand(commandToRun, sudoPassword);
}

sudoCommand() async {
  final sudoPassword = 'mySudoPassword!';
  final commandToRun = 'sudo systemctl stop myServiceName';

  await executeSudoCommand(commandToRun, sudoPassword);
}
```